# Define $T:L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ by $T(f)(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds$. Show that $\|T\|< \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

> Let $L^2 (0,1)$ be the Hilbert space of square integrable functions on the interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Define $T:L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ by $$T(f)(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds.$$
> Show that $\lVert T\rVert< \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

**Attempt**:

$$\begin{align}
\|T(f)\|_{2}^{2}&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds\right)^2 dt\\&= \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{t} \mathbb {1}_{[0,t]} f(s) ds\right)^2 dt\\&< \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{t} \mathbb {1}_{[0,t]} |f(s)|^2 ds\right) dt \\&\leq \int_{0}^{1}t\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f(s)|^2 ds\right)dt \\&=\left(\int_{0}^{1} tdt\right)\|f\|_{2}^{2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\|f\|_{2}^{2}
\end{align}.$$

**Question**: I'm a bit confused if my 3rd and 4th line makes sense or not Just to be clear, I used convexity in the 3rd line and Hölder's inequality in the 4th line. Also note we have a similar question answered here but the inequality was not strict.

Comment: In general the strict inequality for any single function does not imply the strict inequality for the operator norm. This is true for compact operators. In your case the operator is indeed compact. This argument should be added to your solution.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how to show that this operator is compact

Comment: At the moment I do no see the direct argument. The operator is  Hilbert-Schmidt hence it is compact. Are you familiar with this class of operators ?

Comment: No. Not really. I'm not aware of that.

Comment: I'm not sure about your 3rd and 4th lines. I think you should just use Cauchy Schwarz.

Comment: For the direct argument for compactness, you can take a weakly convergent sequence $(f_n)_n$ and show that $T(f_n)$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$, using the dominated convergence theorem and seeing that $\int_0^1 1_{[0,t]}(s) f_n(s)\mathrm{d}s = \langle f_n, 1_{[0,t]}\rangle_{L^2} \to 0$.

Comment: @podiki  I think The Cauchy Schwartz will not give me strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoB this is helpful.

Comment: Another way of showing compactness is to represent the operator $T$ as $T:L^2\to C[0,1]$ composed with the inclusion map  from $C[0,1]$  to $L^2.$ The first one is compact due to  the Arzeli-Ascoli theorem. Therefore the composition is a compact operator.